# UPDATE operation using INNER JOIN from 3 tables

Tags: sql, database, libreoffice

I'm trying to UPDATE two fields in one table, with information that is on a third table, which is referenced by a second table. The third table has fields for "weight" that are populated, that I was to update the first table's "weight" fields. They are related by a "serial number", but the number is in a different format in the first and third table. The second table is basically a reference that has the "serial number" in each format.

I created a query that returns data from the first and the third tables using the second table to relate the fields:

```
SELECT  
tbl_inv_main.invnum,
tbl_inv_main.model,
tbl_inv_main.serial,
tbl_viper_ref.reformattedserial,
tbl_mpn_viper.dryweight,
tbl_mpn_viper.wetweight
 FROM tbl_inv_main 
INNER JOIN tbl_viper_ref 
ON   tbl_inv_main.serial = tbl_viper_ref.serial
INNER JOIN tbl_mpn_viper
ON tbl_mpn_viper.serial = tbl_viper_ref.reformattedserial
```

But Now what I want to do is basically the same thing but update the first table with the "weight" data from the third table.

I tried making a command to update the first table using the same INNER JOIN statements from my query.

What I have come up with so far is:

```
UPDATE "tbl_inv_main"
SET 
tbl_inv_main.dryweight = tbl_mpn_viper.dryweight,
tbl_inv_main.wetweight = tbl_mpn_viper.wetweight
FROM tbl_inv_main
INNER JOIN tbl_viper_ref 
ON   tbl_inv_main.serial =tbl_viper_ref.serial
INNER JOIN tbl_mpn_viper
ON tbl_mpn_viper.serial = tbl_viper_ref.reformattedserial
```

From other sources I've read that should UPDATE the records in the first table with the data from the records from the third table.

I am using libreoffice Base. When I try to run the above UPDATE commands I get the following error:
    Column not found: DRYWEIGHT in statement [    UPDATE "tbl_inv_main"
    SET 
    tbl_inv_main.dryweight]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
UPDATE tbl_inv_main final
SET 
    final.dryweight = m.dryweight,
    final.wetweight = m.wetweight



FROM tbl_inv_main i
   INNER JOIN tbl_viper_ref v ON   i.serial =v.serial
   INNER JOIN tbl_mpn_viper m ON  v.reformattedserial = m.serial

   Where final.serial =i.serial
```

Comment: tried this and it didn't work. 

1: Column not found: DRYWEIGHT in statement [UPDATE "tbl_inv_main" final
SET 
    final.dryweight]

Comment: Hi Cenobium, are you sure that tbl_inv_main contain column dryweight and wetweight, are sure u are updating correct table.

Comment: yes, tbl_inv_main is the table I wanted to update
I am using hsqldb in libreoffice base, which is fairly particular about its syntax